# Magento global variables appear empty

Tags: php, event-observer, magento-1, global-variable

I have a custom module that subscribes to an event called `catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_after`. In the observer I am setting a variable (E.g `$_GET['test'] = true`)

Then later in my `.phtml` file I am accessing that to do logic based on the variable. It works well, however, once launched on one of our client's webshop, all the globals like `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST` appears empty.

My guess is that there is a redirect happening, but then I ask myself why in the world would someone do that, as it definitely messes up most 3rd party extensions. But I might be wrong though.

Any other ideas of why would this be happening ?

P.S Here's a subset of var dump of `$GLOBALS` variable in the frontend:

> array(16) { ["_GET"]=> array(1) { ["limit"]=> string(2) "12" }
>   ["_POST"]=> array(0) { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the using of the `$_SESSION` global variable is solution for you, because after the redirect your server drops all of the `$_REQUEST` variables.

Here is [answer for similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710161/global-php-variables-not-saving-after-redirect):

> Global variables are not persistent between http requests, like a
>   redirect. You have to use a session to store this data between
>   requests.

Comment: I really hate the sessions as I will have to clear my variables after they are read, but I guess there's no other option. P.S Do you have any idea why would someone be doing these redirects? Is there a purpose? Security issue or whatever?

Comment: @Emke You should deeply research this problem. In my opinion it's bug or just a bad code.

Comment: @Emke Well written redirect should save all request data, because you can transfer through it the product id or other important information.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info. I will forward the issue towards the shop's developers. Meanwhile, I will hard code the module to use sessions for them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise using the Magento registry rather than setting values using the GET variable.

```
// Set the registry value
Mage::register('test', TRUE);

// Gets the registry value
$registryValue = Mage::registry('test');
```

Of course, if it is redirecting your request then this also won't work :)

Comment: exactly, as there's a redirect happening, I can't use that either. And I need the variable to be request scope (and read it on the frontend). I don't feel like using sessions and deleting the variables once I read them, sounds like too much overhead

Comment: Right solution. Direct use of a of global variables is not a good practice.

Comment: @Emke can you get your access logs from the server and copy the contents from when you access the pages?

Comment: It's not a solution, as it doesn't yet solve my problem :)

Comment: @Paul here's a filtered subset of access logs http://pastebin.com/SLeKcdnV

Comment: @Emke thanks. Do you have a copy of the logs with just the initial request to the page and then when the page is finally loaded? Is this a product page or category listing as well? I can see a couple of 500 error codes in there - do you know what these are?